# CKEDITOR 4 How to define collapsed and not collapsed button groups?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I added CKEDITOR 4 to input with this config:

```
editor = CKE.replace($element[0].childNodes[0], {
      toolbarCanCollapse: true,
      toolbarStartupExpanded: false,
      toolbar: [
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote' ] },
        '/'
      ]
    });
```

I need to first toolbar group been not collapsed by default, but i got all groups collapsed:

[image]

And all groups expanded when click on collapser arrow:

[image]

How can i define which button groups should collapse and which should not collapse?

Answer (score 2):

The [toolbarCanCollapse](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarCanCollapse) setting does not affect toolbar groups itself, but only the whole toolbar. It is not possible to collapse only single toolbar groups with available CKEditor config (you may however, write some custom code to do this).

Same with [toolbarStartupExpanded](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarStartupExpanded) config which affects the whole toolbar (setting whether the toolbar should be expanded when the editor is loaded).